# MySQL запрос срабатывает один раз, второй выдаёт ошибку

Tags: php, mysql, база-данных, form

Между двумя таблицами есть связь, значение `id` в таблице `lobby` должно передаваться в ячейку `id`, уже в таблице `message`. Вот структура двух таблиц:

`messages`:
[image: lobby]

`lobby`:
[image: lobby]

И когда я ввожу в форму сообщение, то первое сообщение для лобби добавляется в базу данных и выводится на экран, а когда ввожу второе, то ничего в базу данных не заносится и появляется ошибка:

> Problem with SQL: INSERT INTO messages(id, message1) VALUES (176, \'my
>   text\')

Вот код, который добавляет в базу данные:

```
<?php 
 require_once 'config.php';
$message = FormChars($_POST['message']); // Получаем форму

$db->query('SELECT * FROM lobby'); // Получаем id нашего lobby ...
$data = $db->Get();
foreach ($data as $key => $value)

{
$lobby_id = $value['id']; // ... Получили 
}

// Вносим в таблицу messages - id нашего лобби и само сообщение

$db->Query("INSERT INTO messages(id, message1) VALUES ($lobby_id, '$message')");     

echo $message; 
?>
```

Буду очень признателен, если кто-то откликнется...

Comment: У вас поле messages.id является уникальным? Первичным ключом? Если да, то в него нельзя помещаться одинаковые значения $lobby_id, как это происходит при размещении второго ответа.

Comment: Оффтопик: часть "Получаем id нашего lobby" это готовый анти-пример. Не надо вычитывать всю таблицу чтобы получить одно скалярное значение. Непонятно какой именно айди вы получите — нет ограничивающего условия. Где-то должен быть `WHERE` !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`id` - уникальный ключ в таблице `messages`? Добавь в таблицу `messages` новое поле `lobby_id` и замени

```
$db->Query("INSERT INTO messages(id, message1) VALUES ($lobby_id, '$message')");
```

на

```
$db->Query("INSERT INTO messages(lobby_id, message1) VALUES ($lobby_id, '$message')");
```

Comment: Йеа. Работает, спасибо мужик.

Comment: @BimBam если ответ помог решить Вашу проблему, не забудьте отметить его как "Лучший"